# Assign specific type to compatible object

Tags: typescript

i have the following situation:

I have a function that returns States[] (that is an object of strings) and i want to assign them to an object of strings

```
interface State {
  name: string;
  adminName1: string;
  countryCode: string;
  countryName: string;
}
```

`const myStates : <{ [id: string]: string}[]> = getStates()`

Which returns:

`Type 'State[]' is not assignable to type '{ [id: string]: string; }[]'.`

(I need that because i have a functions working with `{ [id: string]: string}[]` type )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add index signature to the interface

```
interface State {
  name: string;
  adminName1: string;
  countryCode: string;
  countryName: string;
  [key: string]: string;
}
```